# Determine if foreign key table has any links to primary key table with LINQ & DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5, c#-3.0, datatable

I have 2 datatables.

One is the master the other is the detail

When someone goes to delete a master record how can I check that there are no rows in my detail datatable that relate to the master table's ID.

**UPDATE:** The user has the ability to select more than one master record at a time

I want to use LINQ if possible.

I started looking at DataTable.Rows.Cast()......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need LINQ for this.

Instead, you can check `masterRow.GetChildRows("RelationName").Length`.

**EDIT**: You should use a DataRelation.

If you really don't want to, you can check

```
childTable.AsEnumerable().Any(dr => dr["ParentIdColumn"] == someValue)
```

**EDIT**: To check for multiple parents:

```
var parentKeys = parentRows.Select(dr => dr["id"]).ToList();

if (childTable.AsEnumerable().Any(dr => parentKeys.Contains(["ParentIdColumn"])))
```

Comment: Yup thanks for the updated answer however I just looked and they can select more than one master record so I need to check wheter there are any child rows based on the master records selected